# Smart Device Framework highlights?

Tags: .net, compact-framework, smart-device-framework

I am thinking about introducing OpenNETCF's Smart Device Framework at my company, as I like the SafeHandle class. But I would like to know what else is good in it. Anyone found a good blogpost or something with the most useful classes and functions in OpenNETCF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We get this question from time to time, and it's actually hard to answer because there's just so much in there.

So here's a list of my favorites, by namespace:

- OpenNETCF.IO

  - FFT (self-explanatory)
  - MemoryMappedFile (IPC data tool)
  - StreamInterfaceDriver (base class for almost any driver-level access)
  - PhysicalAddressPointer (great for direct register access on hardware)
- OpenNETCF.IO.Threading

  - NamedMutex and EventWaitHandle (you can actually use named system events, so they're system unique - again good for IPC)
- OpenNETCF.ToolHelp (good for anything where you need a list of processes, threads, etc)
- OpenNETCF.Diagnostics

  - TextWriterTraceListener and Trace2 (you can do logging just like on the desktop)
- OpenNETCF.Drawing.Imaging (all sorts of stuff for the Imaging namespace - good for alpha blending, rotations, etc)
- OpenNETCF.Net.NetworkInformation (everything you ever wanted to know abpout any of your network interfaces)
- OpenNETCF.Windows.Forms

  - OwnerDrawnList (for those times when a boring list just won't do)
  - RoundGauge (ugly looking, but a great code example on a complex control without flickering)
- OpenNETCF.WindowsCE

  - LargeIntervalTime (for firing events even when the device is suspended)
- OpenNETCF.WindowsCE.Messaging

  - P2PMessageQueue (nothing better for queued IPC)

Now there is a *lot* more than this in there - there's no way I could reasonably list it all.  This is just a sampling of my favorites/most commonly used from quickly browsing the source tree.